# Shared Data Source for Excel

Tags: sql, excel

I am currently creating reporting within excel for lets say 'Non Advanced Users'. I Have successfully created this in and I can execute the stored procedure with parameters typed into excel cells. But when I send this to another user it is saying that it is unable to connect to the data source. Is there a way I could tell excel to use a data source on our network. The connection has SQL Authentication. Basically I want to try and avoid having to create data sources via excel on 100+ machines!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can save the `connection setting` in the excel file itself, and just send out that file. See picture below for step-by-step guide.
Remember to **CLEAR** (uncheck) the '*Always Use Connection File*' in Step 6.
[image]